# Community user unable to change password via custom change password visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com-sites, customer-community

I have a Visualforce page with an extension that is supposed to allow a community user to change their password.

When the logged in community user (User License = Customer Community) uses my page, the change password process returns a page message of:

```
The system is unable to change your password.
```

I've made sure the current password and password policies are adhered to. (they cause different messages anyway).

Has anyone received this message before, and if so, what's causing it?

**Extension method:**

```
public PageReference changePassword()
{
    // this always returns null.
    // if there are any errors, they're added to ApexPages page messages
    PageReference changePasswordReturnPage = Site.changePassword(newPassword1, newPassword2, password);

    return null;
}
```

**Visualforce Page extract:**

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputSecret value="{!pageExtension.password}" html-placeholder="Current Password" />
    <apex:inputSecret value="{!pageExtension.newPassword1}" html-placeholder="New Password" />
    <apex:inputSecret value="{!pageExtension.newPassword2}" html-placeholder="Repeat Password" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!pageExtension.changePassword}" value="Change Password" rerender="change-password-result" />
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Check if the profile has 'Require a minimum 1 day password lifetime' enabled. If yes disable the same try with change password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this was an intermittent salesforce issue.

Without changing the code, the next day the `Site.changePassword()` method worked as expected.

It's a bit concerning, because it was never clear what the problem was.
Using the `System.setPassword()` worked during this time period, so I'm not sure what problems salesforce was having, or how we're supposed to handle this properly.